# Moment js with angular 2 js add times

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs

Hello everyone i'm working on a project that uses time a lot so i'm using moment js but i can't deal with it i don't know why i'm working on a website exactly like toggl.com of course i wrote the structure with angular2 and this is my code --> this app.component.html which hold the input field and timer and button for start and stop timer

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row wrapper">
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-9 first">
   <input type="text" class="form-control title" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" #task>
  </div>
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-3 second hiddden">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="00:00:00" (click)="showdiv()" [(ngModel)]="timer" #time>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 font">
      <i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-3x first" aria-hidden="true" *ngIf="play" (click)="startPause()"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-stop-circle fa-3x second" aria-hidden="true" *ngIf="pause" (click)="startPlay(task.value, time.value)"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row hidden_one">
    <div class="start-end" *ngIf="show">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Start">Start</label><br>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" class="startTime" value="{{startTime}}" #val (blur)="validate(val.value)">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Start">Stop</label><br>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" class="startTime" [(ngModel)]="stopTime" [disabled]="pause">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

 <times-list [tasksList]="tasks"></times-list>
```

as u can see in the pic below when i click on input timer filed there is a div start --> which fires when i click on play button and stop which fires when click on stop button or even when i focus on the timer and her is my app-component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { timeInterface } from './timeInterface';
import { timesList } from './times-list-component';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 templateUrl: './html/app-component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./css/app-component.css']
})

export class AppComponent  { 
  placeholder:string = "What are you working on?";
  play:boolean = true;
  pause:boolean = false;
  show:boolean=false;// For Showing The Hidden Div
  countup:any;
  timeSum :any;
  timer:string = "00:00:00";
  // hidden Div Start Time
  startTime: any;
  stopTime: any;
  bs:any;
  bbs:any;
  // Array to Hold The Tasks With Time
  tasks:timeInterface[] =[];

  startPause() {
   this.bs = moment();
   this.startTime = this.bs.format('LT');
   this.play = false;
   this.pause = true;
   let sec= 0;
   let min = 0;
   let hour = 0;
   this.countup = setInterval(() => {
    if(sec === 59) {
      min++;
      sec = 0;
    }else if(min > 59) {
      hour++;
      min = 0;
    }else {
      sec++;
    }
   this.timer = `${this.pad(hour)}:${this.pad(min)}:${this.pad(sec)}`;
  }, 1000);

}

startPlay(name:string, time:any) {
  this.play = true;
  this.pause = false;
  this.timer = "00:00:00";
  clearInterval(this.countup);
  //push the task to array
  if(name == "") {
   // this.placeholder = "(no description)";
    name = "Add description";
    this.tasks.push({title: name, time: time});
    console.log(this.tasks);
  } else {
    name = name;
    this.tasks.push({title: name, time: time});
  }

}

pad(num:number, size:number=2): string { // to add zero before sec if it < 10
  var s = num+"";
  while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
  return s;
}
//Show the hidden div
showdiv() {
  this.bbs = moment();
  this.show = true;
  this.stopTime = this.bbs.format('LT');
  if(!this.pause) {
    this.startTime = this.stopTime
  }
}
// Validate input value
validate(val:string) {
  let temp =this.startTime;
  let x = temp;
  this.startTime = moment(val, "LT", true).isValid() ? val : this.startTime;
  if(moment(this.startTime).isSame(this.stopTime)) {
    console.log("true");
  }else {
    console.log("false");

  }
 }
}
```

[image]
so i have questions
1/ there is a function firse when the blue event happens on the start input

```
validate(val:string) {
  let temp =this.startTime;
  let x = temp;
  this.startTime = moment(val, "LT", true).isValid() ? val : this.startTime;
}
```

this function check the value of he field after the field if the value like this 4:01 AM not 4:1 AM because i'm using LT it replaces the original value with it else it return the original value what ever it is firstly i doesn't work in the else statement and also replaces the original value with the new one 
2/in toggl.com if i deletet the start value and Am||PM and wrote any number it calculates and check if the number > stop value or not  or even before it and calcute the difference between the 2 values and replace the timer with this value for ex:
if start input value is : 1:10 pm and the stop value is 1:10 pm and i deleted the start value which is 1:10 pm and i wrote only 2 it takes it as 2:00 PM and calculate the difference which is 50min it takes it as 0:50:00 and replace the timer with it how can i do that and why the 2 is taken as in this format 2:00 and why it is PM not am
3/ how can i add two times like: 00:01:20 + 00:00:20 = 00:01:40
how can i do that with moment js thanks in advance